# Is there a way in C# to create a design template for a component

Tags: c#, templates, components, modeling

Is there a way in C# to create a design template for a component (a button for example)  All the buttons in the project will inherit the design from the template.
And whenever I change the template all the buttons will inherit the change.
I want that my application will have the same look
all the buttons will look the same, all the text box.....
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want to do can be achieved by creating your own inherited class of a control. e.g.

```
public class yourbuttontemplate : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    yourbuttontemplate() //constructor
    {
        this.Height=20;
        this.Width=40;
        this.BackColor=Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

Once you build your project, your button should be available in the toolbox and you can use this button instead of the default Windows.Forms.Button.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Your solution is very good and helped my very much. (I thought that only user control appears in the toolbox).

I have one observation:

 If I add the control via the tool box C# designer automatically overrides some of the control's properties. So in order for to inheritance to be complete the user should delete the properties that were overridden by the designer each time it adds a new control.